# How to know the element that triggered the event in hover jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to get the element? i.e:

```
$('#obj').hover(function() { },function() { /* here, i need to know the element that triggered this out event. */ });
```

thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/yc552/1/ take a look here - might shed some  light on the situation.

Answer (score 3):

It's called [`ev.target`](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-event-target)

```
function (ev) {
    var target = ev.target
    // target triggered event
}
```

Of course you may not want the target but rather want the [`currentTarget`](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-event-currenttarget)

The `currentTarget` is the element the event handler is bound to.

As for the value of `this` in the callback. It's generally `ev.currentTarget`, jQuery uses that, the current DOM4 WD uses `ev.target` and the current DOM4 ED uses `ev.currentTarget`. I belief it's generally `ev.currentTarget` in legacy engines.

Note that if your not using jQuery but using the IE propitiatory event system then `ev.srcElement` is the equivelant of `ev.target`

Comment: The `currentTarget` property is rarely useful as most event handlers (especially DOM 0) have the `this` value bound to whatever the handler is attached to.

Comment: @MattMcDonald do you have a link to DOM0 event handlers where it states the value of the `this` in callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery event binding, it passed you back an event object that you can access in your function, that object has the control in it, i think its targetElement or something like that ... so change your code to `$('#obj').hover(function(ev) { }`
and ev.targetElement should be what you're looking for.

Comment: ahh target ... and Raynos ur quick lol i was just about to hit submit answer" and boom i saw the notification that u already answered lol